# Speakers will not work after I use USB Headset

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, usb-headset

I am trying to configure my SteelSeries Siberia V2 Frost USB Headset to work with my 2.0 speakers using a jack. My goal is to find a easy way (no restart) to switch playback from my headset and my speakers and vice-versa.

If i plug my headset in and make it the default device then restart my application/web page then the sounds works out of headset. If I switch the default to my speakers and restart apps/web pages  then sound does not play.

I know my speakers are on because if I configure them through windows and test, the sounds play, and sounds also play when I test it through my audio manager. Even if I unplug my headset, I still cannot get sound out of my speakers unless I restart

My audio manager is RealTek HD Audio Manager, Windows 7 x64.

I have tried the speaker back, usb front. speaker front, usb in front port. I have not tried speaker back, usb back.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not with my sound setup but with Chrome.

Chrome has a known bug where it wont change play back when default device is switched.

To fix, add -disable-audio-output-resampler to the chrome shortcut in the target box.